# How to recognize particular image is animating during imageview animation?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimageview, uibutton, calayer

I am creating a timer which is used to play a song for 6 seconds.But i want that whenever i clicked the button it will recognized the particular image which is animating at that particular instant.For that i used CALayer but it is not giving the image name.

**This is my code:**

```
-(void)playSong
{
    timerButton.imageView.animationImages =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage   imageNamed:@"Timer6.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Timer5.png"],
                                                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"Timer4.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Timer3.png"],
                                                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"Timer2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Timer1.png"],
                                                                   nil];
    timerButton.imageView.animationDuration=6.0; 
    [self.player play];
    [timerButton.imageView startAnimating];
}

- (void)handleLongPressGestures:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
 if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
 {
       CALayer *player1 = timerButton.imageView.layer;

 }
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot get the image name from a `UIImageView` or `UIImage` object.

You could, however, set an **accessibility identifier** to a `UIImage` object that, in your case, could be it's file name.
Then simply doing `someUIImageObject.accessibilityIdentifier` should return the file name.
<sup>([refer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16894178/2857130))</sup>

Example:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];
[image setAccessibilityIdentifier:@"someImage"];

NSLog(@"%@",image.accessibilityIdentifier);
```

---

Now... you'd expect `timerButton.imageView.image.accessibilityIdentifier` to give you the image name but that's not how it works when the `UIImageView` is animating.
This time, we need to access it via the `UIImageView`s `animationImages` array property.
For this, we will need some custom logic to get the `UIImage` object from this `animationImages` array.

We'll first record the time we started animating the images and with some basic maths, we can calculate the index of the `animationImages` array that is currently being displayed in the `UIImageView`.
<sup>([refer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17848940/2857130))</sup>

---

### Answer (code):

```
-(void)playSong
{
    NSMutableArray *arrImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 6 ; i > 0 ; i--) {
        //Generate image file names: "Timer6.png", "Timer5.png", ..., "Timer1.png"
        NSString *strImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Timer%d.png",i];

        //create image object
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:strImageName];
        //remember image object's filename
        [image setAccessibilityIdentifier:strImageName];

        [arrImages addObject:image];
    }

    [timerButton.imageView setAnimationImages:arrImages];
    [timerButton.imageView setAnimationDuration:6.0f];
    [timerButton.imageView setAnimationRepeatCount:0];

    [self.player play];
    [timerButton.imageView startAnimating];

    //record start time
    startDate = [NSDate date]; //declare "NSDate *startDate;" globally
}
```

---

```
- (void)handleLongPressGestures:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        [self checkCurrentImage];
    }
}
```

---

```
-(void)checkCurrentImage
{
    //logic to determine which image is being displayed from the animationImages array

    NSTimeInterval durationElapsed = -1 * [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    NSTimeInterval durationPerFrame = timerButton.imageView.animationDuration / timerButton.imageView.animationImages.count;
    int currentIndex = (int)(durationElapsed / durationPerFrame) % timerButton.imageView.animationImages.count;

    UIImage *imageCurrent = timerButton.imageView.animationImages[currentIndex];
    NSString *strCurrentImage = imageCurrent.accessibilityIdentifier;

    NSLog(@"%@",strCurrentImage);
}
```